Start up failure of spring batch application built with graalvm native
Having an issue on startup with this spring batch application I have written. This works fine running with the standard JVM. Building the native image I see the following error on startup:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxb': The program tried to reflectively access the proxy class inheriting

   [jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType, org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.annotation.Locatable]

without it being registered for runtime reflection. Add [jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType, org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.annotation.Locatable] to the dynamic-proxy metadata to solve this problem. Note: The order of interfaces used to create proxies matters. See https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/#dynamic-proxy for help.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.instantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:987)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350)
    at org.za.sampra.parser.Application.main(Application.java:25)
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)
Caused by: org.graalvm.nativeimage.MissingReflectionRegistrationError: The program tried to reflectively access the proxy class inheriting

   [jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType, org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.annotation.Locatable]

without it being registered for runtime reflection. Add [jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType, org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.model.annotation.Locatable] to the dynamic-proxy metadata to solve this problem. Note: The order of interfaces used to create proxies matters. See https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/#dynamic-proxy for help.
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.reflect.MissingReflectionRegistrationUtils.errorForProxy(MissingReflectionRegistrationUtils.java:108)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.reflect.proxy.DynamicProxySupport.getProxyClass(DynamicProxySupport.java:180)
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:48)
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1034)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.annotation.LocatableAnnotation.create(LocatableAnnotation.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:29)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getClassOrPackageAnnotation(ClassInfoImpl.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getAccessType(ClassInfoImpl.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:46)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:46)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:332)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:413)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1111)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:140)
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:269)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:258)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:238)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:386)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:605)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromClasses(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:574)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:520)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    ... 18 more

The environment I am running on is as follows:

OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 23.0.1+11.1 (build 23.0.1+11-jvmci-b01)
XUbuntu 24.10
Maven 3.9.9
spring boot 3.4.1
graalvm metadata version: 0.3.15

I realize that additional metadata needs to be supplied for graalvm to resolve the issue, but I am not sure how to go about it.
For the jaxb runtime I am using:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

The default version for spring boot is version 4.0.5 however when using that version I receive the following:
Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxb': Unknown JAXB exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.instantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:987)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350)
    at org.misc.parser.Application.main(Application.java:25)
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:990)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:531)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 8 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.Recording does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.Recording
Property recordingLocalIdCollectingSociety appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant null?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.Recording
Property isrc appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant null?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.Recording
Property recordingTitleCollectingSociety appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant null?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.Recording
Property mainArtists appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant null?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.Recording
Property mainArtist appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant null?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.MainArtists
Property mainArtistLocalIdCollectiongSociety appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant null?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.MainArtist
Property mainArtistNameCollectionSociety appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant null?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.misc.parsers.model.sdeg.MainArtist

    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1115)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:44)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:373)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:605)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromClasses(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:574)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:520)
    ... 21 more


